# I have iCloud but I don't know how to use Find My iPhone

Tags: ios, icloud, iphone, find-my-iphone

So last night I was at home watching movies and I went to get on my phone and I noticed it missing. My phone IS on and I THOUGHT the ringer was on until I called it. Many websites say you can download Find My iPhone from iCloud but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Please be aware that Find my Phone will not be able to pinpoint your phone's location within your house, just that it's in/near your house or at another location.

Comment: @pdd That depends how big your house is and how many Wi-Fi routers you have inside your house :)

Comment: @GeorgeGarside That may be true, however, I've always found the pinpoint accuracy to be off (I have multiply devices and they are always shown scattered throughout my property, even when they are located on the same desk). Better to use Find my Phone to play a sound on the device, especially when you don’t have another phone to call it with.

Answer (score 1):

**Go to [icloud.com/#find](http://icloud.com/#find) and log in.** No download is necessary and your device should be located on a map and allow you to lock/erase/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sign into iCloud.com with the same iCloud ID registered on the phone.
One of the "apps" in iCloud.com should be "Find my iPhone."
[image]